# Is there going to be an SO flavor for gamers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Joel keeps suggesting such a site in the SO podcast, and imho it would be a perfect fit for the platform. Apparently Jeff wants it to be part of superuser.com.  Isn’t the gamers’ community large enough to deserve its own site?

Comment: There are millions more games out there than programming models/paradigms. So, the reputation wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: There are tons of existing gamer sites. And looking at how they're designed, i'm not sure SO would be a good fit... you'd have to clog it up with blinking ads, use a garish color scheme with lots of contrast for everything but the actual content text, and lock down every potentially-useful portion behind a membership + more ads wall. It'd be a lot of work...

Comment: God Rob, are you looking for a "Nail in the Coffin" badge or something?

Answer (score 9):

What's wrong with GameFAQs (other than their connection to Gamespot and lack of ponies)?  They even have a question and answer system now.

Comment: +1 There are a number of established gaming communities, including GameFAQs <3

Comment: While GameFaqs is unbeatable in terms of content, an SO-like site would have its appeal, if only because the improved usability, wouldn’t it?

Comment: The SO paradigm would be an incremental improvement, imo, but not the same revolution it has been for programming. If GameFAQs followed the expert-sex-change model, then it would be a different story.

Comment: The best thing about GameFAQs is the long-form contributions; that is, the strategy guides that made the site worthwhile to begin with.  SO can't really improve these.  The message boards and question and answer system could be improved by SO, but that's like changing the paint job on a race car.  Sure, it's an improvement, but it doesn't really make it that much better.

Comment: @Pesto - red cars with lots of logos go faster. Everyone knows that.

Comment: @Jon B: Hmmm... that *sounds* like science.  It must be true.

Comment: @Jon B No no no.  Not logos.  It's the GT stripes!  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090304082006AAb2liO

Comment: Their forums are what's wrong. The FAQs themselves are alright. Besides, there are many dedicated places and wikis dedicated to games that are very well furnished. I'm thinking the Fallout wikia, (http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Wiki), for example.

Answer (score 6):

If they include video games as part of SuperUser I will be incredibly unhappy.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is worth remembering that having the site is only half the battle.  Actually, I'm lying.  Having the site is about 2% of the battle.  Getting a critical mass of users is the other 98%.

In the case of StackOverflow, it was the combined (and separate) fame of Jeff and Joel that got the ball rolling; otherwise the site would have likely languished without enough quality questions and answers to get it going.

So, the question is not "Does the Gamers community deserve its own site?", but rather, who has enough credibility in the Gamer community to get a similar site going?

Comment: You are right, although one could say there is a substantial overlap between the programmer/sysadmin/computer enthusiast crowd and the gaming circle. Could be a good starting point for creating such a community.

Comment: there would at least be a post on kotaku and joystiq on the day the site launched, which would drive lots of people to the site.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any plans for anything like this, but you can make your own:

> http://stackexchange.com

If anyone is interested, I own:

> http://fragoverflow.com
>   http://fragoverflow.org
>   http://fragoverflow.net

Comment: Are you just copy/pasting this at this point?

Comment: @TheTXI: That is the same as what I wonder about these questions honestly.

Comment: Announced as available on September 1, and rather pricey, particularly as the community is not guaranteed.  It could be a great place to sell online game ads, though.

Comment: fragoverflow - brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

There is one now, it's called Arqade. You can find it at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect to see *one* site for games - I'd expect to see specific sites for specific games, or at least genres.

I know one of the benefits of the SO model is that with tags you can sort of categorise without segmenting, but I would expect a popular new game to have enough interest to make it worth having a specific site - within that site, the tags could be for modding, achievements, tactics, walkthroughs etc.

Likewise one site could cover a whole series, e.g. "EvilOverflow" for the Resident Evil games.

I'd expect this to be one of the uses of an open sourced SO - or possibly StackExchange. Definitely better to get it maintained by the community around that game rather than by Jeff et al.

Comment: ZombieOverflow could cover everything from Resident Evil to Dead Rising to Left 4 Dead

Comment: An xbox-oriented site and coming full circle with the badge system :) ?

Comment: Leonardo, I wanted to develop a website once that was like a facebook for gamers, but I gave up when I couldn't get XBox Live API access for things like badge tracking :(

Comment: one site for all games, with tags for specific games and genres would make more sense - there are thousands upon thousands of popular games

Comment: @Steven: That's my point - there's *too much* for one site, IMO. There's much less overlap between people playing (say) Animal Crossing and people playing RE5 than there is between people coding in Perl and people coding in C#. I think you could have a viable site for either individual genres or game series though.

Comment: i don't know that there'd be enough interest for the "experts" on a single game to keep sticking around and answering questions on a site dedicated to just one game.  but if the site were for all games and you posted a resident evil question, chances are someone who is familiar with resident evil will see the question

Comment: @Kip: The only way of having that working is to significantly improve the tag system in terms of only showing the tags you're interested in etc.

Comment: @Jon: I've recently had the misfortune of having to work with ColdFusion, and I find that I get answers to those questions very quickly, despite the fact that it's a rarely-used platform.  I was thinking that whatever allows the few programmers who know coldfusion to find my questions on SO could also help other people find, for example, resident evil questions to answer

Answer (score 2):

I think that an SO-variant for games would be quite successful - especially since you could generate revenue through targeted advertising. Based on which questions people answer, upvote, or read, you could deliver ads for games that match the genres that they like.

Hmmm, I should probably patent that idea...

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I don't see what gaming questions have to do with the questions asked in SO, SF, or (shortly) SU.  I think a version for computer games could be very nice for computer gamers, but somebody would need to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

There is a StackExchange site for gamers that has been up for a while: [GameLegend](http://www.gamelegend.com).  It's been having a very difficult time building a community so far.  I've been trying my best, but I'm just one gamer.